# Number of Requests allowed by Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I m using facebook php-sdk for development.

I am not pretty sure about how many requests are allowed by Facebook. I read in a few stackoverflow answers that its 600 requests for 600 seconds. But, I don't think I am able to understand it properly. Is it 600 batch requests we can make with each batch request allowed upto 50 of them as given in Facebook Documentation or is it 600 in total i.e. only 12 batch requests allowed? But even in any of the cases, the scenarios I faced do not satisfy the fact.

My experience with this bulk request has been very bad and been very weird. I will just brief you with what all happened with my experimentation with Facebook Graph API.

Scene 1 : I used a batch request for 50 posts, it gave me data for 28 posts, but return without data for the others.

Scene 2 : I made batches of 20 posts, it gave me complete data for the first batch, but in the next batch, it just gave data for 13 of them.

Scene 3 : I kept the batches to 20 urls, but introduced a sleep timer for 2 seconds. It gave me data for the first 40 posts, but in the 3rd batch request, only 5 posts' data was fetched, but for remaining 15 posts, there was no data returned by facebook. (This simply negates the 600 seconds and 600 requests answer.)

Scene 4 : I kept the batches to 20 urls, but introduced a sleep timer for 5 seconds. This helped me get all the data.

The problem lies for me when the number of posts increase to upto 1000 or more, then even after putting a 2 second sleep after every request, facebook doesn't return any data after a certain period of time.

I hope someone knows the answer for this !!

Comment: You should be receiving an exception if you're being actively rate limited - usually 'application request limit reached' - the app's insights will also show what throttling or blocking is taking place

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But I have to wait for another 2 days before getting the error related to it because Insights are reported by facebook 48 hours later. But I hope that the information I will get will be pretty informative.